# Show different regex message for different user inputs

Tags: javascript, html, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC view with an input field which has a validation on a regular expression which is something like this **^XY[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}$**

and my Html field looks like

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Someclass.Name, new
                {
                    data_val = "true",
                    data_val_required = "Test Required Message",
                    data_val_regex = "Test Invalid Regex Message",
                    data_val_regex_pattern = "^XY[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}$",

                })
```

I have two scenarios

1. When user enters XY12345678901235, which is invalid and we show **"Test Required Message"**

   2. When user enter 123455, which is also invalid, but we should a different message **Error Message 2**

How can achieve the scenario 2?

Thanks

Comment: Might want to put asp.net-mvc and asp.net in the tags if that's what you're using.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil, Thanks I have edited to include the asp.net mvc tag

Comment: If you using unobtrusive client side validation, then you cant. But how do you distinguish between them (i.e. what is the criteria for displaying the 2nd message instead of the 1st)?

Comment: HI @StephenMuecke, I should display the second message when user enters just 12345, which is invalid and doesn't contain the first 2 charecters XY which are part of regex.  And i need to display the first error message if the user input is invalid but still contains XY

Comment: You cannot do this using either validation attributes or unobtrusive client side validation. You will need to write your own javascipt/jquery function that handles the inputs `.change()` event and then tests if its valid or not and displays an appropriate error message (and then of course you will need to do the same test in the POST method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thanks I was thinking if there is a way of calling a javascript function for data_val_regex attribute, and withing the JS function i will decide what message to show

Comment: The `data-val-*` attributes are used by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` so there is no point adding all those attributes (you cant achieve what you want using unobtrusive client side validation). You will need to write your own script.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can you brief me about the script which you are proposing please?

Comment: Bit hard to understand under which conditions you want to display which message - is it - if it begins with "XY" but does not match, then display one message, and if it does not begin with `"XY" and does not match, display a different message?

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to do this using unobtrusive client side validation (using jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js) because it only allows one message per rule. Instead you can handle this in a similar manner by writing your own scripts to mimic the behavior.

Its a bit unclear why your manually adding those `data-val-*` attributes when they are added automatically is you apply the `[Required]` and `[RegularExpression]` attributes to your property. Start by including the `[Required]` attribute to your property so that will be handled in the default manner

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Someclass.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Someclass.Name) // for the [Required] error message
<span id="regexerror" class="field-validation-error"></span> // for the custom message
```

and include the following scripts to handle the textbox `.change()` event to test the value (and display the appropriate message if applicable) and forms submit event to cancel the submit if invalid.

```
var isValid = true;
var regex = /^XY[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}$/;
var prefix = 'XY';
var errorMessage = $('#regexerror');

$('#Someclass_Name').change(function() {
  var name = $(this).val();
  if (!name) { // no value so let client side validation handle it
    return;
  }
  // test if we match the regex
  isValid = regex.test(name);
  if (isValid) {
    errorMessage.text(''); // clear error
  } else {
    if (name.indexOf(prefix) == 0) {
      errorMessage.text('error message 1'); // starts with XY
    } else {
      errorMessage.text('error message 2')
    }
  }
});

$('form').submit(function() {
  return isValid; // will cancel the default submit if false
});
```

Side note: You will of course need to repeat this validation on the server side. Client side validation is a nice bonus, but can be overridden (never trust user input).